# WooCommerce: Updating Product Advanced Information through phpMyAdmin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, phpmyadmin

I have a WooCommerce Shop with 850+ products that needs editing. Without having to purchase an Extended/Pro Plugin to mass edit these products... I am trying to do this through phpMyAdmin.

The site is a little bit of "Add to Cart" and "Ask for Quote", so we're using the RFQ Toolkit Plugin, to handle this. The BIG issue is where I need to Edit All 850+ Products by hand... in the  Advanced Tab for each Product. :(

WooCommerce stores Product information in both the wp_posts and wp_postmeta tables, where WooCommerce Products have "product" listed for the post_type column. Products sold as "Ask for Quote" (because of the RFQ Tookit) have an entry in the wp_postmeta table of [meta_id, post_id, meta_key, meta_value]... where the meta_key is '_gpls_woo_rfq_rfq_enable', and the meta_value of 'yes'.

So, I'm trying to build an UPDATE query in English like this:

Search the wp_posts table for each Item with post_type 'product' and get the ID's (assuming it's the same as post_id in the wp_postmeta table).

Then, using those ID's, create an associated entry in wp_postmeta of [new meta_id, post_id or ID, _gpls_woo_rfq_rfq_enable, yes].

Does this EVEN make sense? If not, I apologize and will further my question with whatever information you need to reasonable answer this question. :)

Sincerely,
Dennis Lambing / Agent CD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you are looking for inserting a new row on the wp_postmeta table (not updating an existing one) for each product, so maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (
    post_id,
    meta_key,
    meta_value
)

SELECT
    ID,
    '_gpls_woo_rfq_rfq_enable',
    'yes'

FROM wp_posts

WHERE post_type = 'product'
```

This makes a new meta for each product with the meta key `_gpls_woo_rfq_rfq_enable` and the value `yes`

Comment: Looks good. :) Thanks. To clarify, do I need to worry about the  meta_id... I suspect it would auto-increment from where it left off, as it appears to be the "index" for the wp_postmeta table.

Comment: Yes, you don't have to worry about setting its value, it would auto-increment itself. If I helped you, I would appreciate if you mark the answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

Much thanks to Fernando M. for your excellent answer! :)

YES, this was exactly what I needed. You are great! :)

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (
    post_id,
    meta_key,
    meta_value
)

SELECT
    ID,
    '_gpls_woo_rfq_rfq_enable',
    'yes'

FROM wp_posts

WHERE post_type = 'product'
```